# MariaDB -> Error: 1062, Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: centos, mariadb, mysql-error-1062

So I'm trying to import geoipcity data into my table like so:

```
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-optionally-enclosed-by="\"" --lines-terminated-by="\n" --host=localhost --user=user --password=passw database_name /var/www/html/GeoLiteCity_20150804/geoip_city.csv
```

But I keep getting the error.

```
Error: 1062, Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Now I saw the question relating to this error has been asked before but I simply don't understand the answers. I'm not that much of a guru, I'm a volunteer IT guy and I have no idea how to resolve this. I tried using this instead:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/html/GeoLiteCity_20150804/geoip_city_ips.csv' INTO TABLE geoip_city_ips;
```

But then it would simply fill the table with "NULL" in all the columns.

My table structure:

```
--
```

### -- Table structure for table `geoip_city`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geoip_city` (
  `locID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` char(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` char(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `dmaCode` char(8) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `areaCode` char(8) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locID`),
  KEY `Index_Country` (`country`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

Some lines from geoip_city:

717543,"MX","32","Zacatecas","98051",22.7833,-102.5833,,
717544,"MX","26","Cananea","84624",30.9500,-110.3000,,
717545,"MX","07","Valles","79040",26.6667,-100.6833,,
717546,"DE","02","Berg","88276",47.9667,11.3500,,
717547,"DE","09","Schwalbach","65824",49.3000,6.8167,,
717548,"RU","48","Moscow","129233",55.7522,37.6156,,
717549,"MX","28","Reynosa","88520",26.0833,-98.2833,,
717550,"PH","40","San Jose","5100",12.4558,121.0459,,
717551,"ES","56","Tarragona","43070",41.1167,1.2500,,
717552,"GB","Z6","","",51.9167,-0.6500,,

Comment: please show some lines from geoip_city and what is the structure of your DB?

Comment: probably whatever's in the csv has a blank value in whatever column youv'e got set as the primary, so `...,,...` would be an empty string, and converted to integer 0 at insert time. if you have 2+ rows like that, there's your error.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback Marc B. But how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm guessing this is a MariaDB issue then since nobody replied? Would going back to Debian solve the issue?

Comment: No. But you can try `sort -u -k1 -n /var/www/html/GeoLiteCity_20150804/geoip_city_ips.csv` and then your mysqlimport  command. But backup .csv first, just in case.

Comment: oops, this might be better: `sort -u -k1 -n /var/www/html/GeoLiteCity_20150804/geoip_city_ips.csv -o /var/www/html/GeoLiteCity_20150804/geoip_city_ips.csv `